# How to avoid memory leaks using Javascript google.maps.places.Autocomplete in Angular ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, maps, ng-view

I'm having trouble with `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` and single page app. Long story short I have a Angular directive with `form` with `input` field in it. The `input` field has autocomplete functionality so when clicked and address typed it shows matching addresses. Its single page app so whe user navigates to the page it loads appropriate `ng-view`. When user navigates away to another page and another content is loaded in `ng-view` memory is not cleared. Using profile and snapshots in Google Chrome I clearly see there is rubbish left over and the form element is detached (its marked in red). This is due to `input` field where `autocomplete` is attached.
I narrowed it down to the line where new `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` is declared. If I remove the call to autocomplete memory clears as it should, otherwise however the entire form where input `aaa` exists stays in memory.
I also clear all the variables on $destroy so it could be garbage collected but nothing seems to work. Is there any solution to this and any way to use Autocomplete in dynamically loaded ng-views without leaking memory?

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                var autocomplete;
var aaa=document.getElementById('address');

                function initializeGoogleMaps() {
                    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                        (aaa), {
                            types: ['geocode']
                        });
                    scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                        $(".pac-container").remove();
                        autocomplete=null;
                    });



    }

        initializeGoogleMaps();
// some other code
```